# How to get image base64 from loaded image from url in CachedNetworkImageProvider Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, tobase64string, base64url

I want to get image base64 from cahcedNetworkImageProvider widget without redownload it to share it in my App.
or if there's a way to share image as a URL and could be saved to the device in flutter

Answer (score 0):

used **flutter_cache_manager** plugin to get cached data through this function

```
  var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
```

and works fine for cached images and if URL is new will download it then get back with file object